# Why am I having trouble connecting to the Infura mainnet?

Tags: json-rpc, infura

I ran the below command, which I understood should've connected me to the mainnet:

```
curl -X POST \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_blockNumber", "params": []}' \ "mainnet.infura.io/my-token
```

but there appears to continue to be some **issue**.

- Any idea why?
- Have I made some syntax error, or am I supposed to be swapping out an actual block number for `eth_blockNumber`, or similar?

To make sure it's clear that I didn't make the following mistake, I did swap out 'my-token' for the 20 digit token Infura generated for me.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What type of issue do you face? Can you add some error code?

Comment: Hi Roman - Thanks for the response.  Yes!  When I attempt to run a script that I need to get working today, I get the following: Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:31:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:87:18)
    at RequestManager.send (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32)
    at Eth.send [as getBalance] ....etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to use HTTPS. This works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_blockNumber", "params": []}' https://mainnet.infura.io/my-token
```